# Laravel oauth2 unauthorized redirect

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am trying to implement oath2 using laravel and passport. however i have managed to make everything up & running. But the problem i am facing is when token expires or without token the url redirects to the laravels login page. I was expecting an unauthorized error message with a status code 401.

oauth2 is implemented using passport. I think laravels default auth is creating the problem.

this is my code in routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('users', "\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getUsers");

    Route::post('permission/add', "\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@createPermission");
    Route::get('permissions', "\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getPermissions");
    Route::get('permission/{param}', "\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getPermission");

    Route::post('role/add', "\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@createRole");
    Route::get('roles', "\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getRoles");

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

[My output when unauthorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWzlV.png)

my config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Check the `$redirectTo` value in your `LoginController.php`

Comment: @Ahsan-Aasim: I think you missed to updated passport authentication driver to `passport` in `config/auth.php`.

Comment: my authentication driver is passport
i added my auth configuration in question if you want to check.

Comment: Why are you accessing API via postman? It should accessed via consumer site. At least to get access?

Comment: yes it will be.. i am currently developing the apis. so postman is the only option to test